# DataTable.Select() Property: Giving Index Out of Bound Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to select only those rows which have Parent ID = 0

`int predecessor = Parent;

        StringBuilder valuePath = new StringBuilder();
        valuePath.Append(Parent.ToString());

DataRow[] drPar;

            while (true)
            {
                drPar = dt.Select("MenuID=" + predecessor);
                if (drPar != null)
                {
                    if (drPar[0]["ParentID"].ToString().Equals("0"))
                    break;
                }`

drPar[0]["ParentID"].ToString().Equals("0") is giving me
Out of Bound exception ..

Help Please !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) does not return `null` when there's no matching `DataRow` but an array with `Length==0`.

But apart from that, why are you using an "infinite" loop for only one statement?

So this should work:

```
drPar = dt.Select("MenuID=" + predecessor);
if (drPar.Length != 0)
{
    if (drPar[0]["ParentID"].ToString().Equals("0"))
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The array drPar must be empty to give this error as it is the only index you use in your code.

Try

```
 if (drPar != null && drPar.Length > 0)
```

Comment: Then how to check if dt.select returns 0 rows  ?